# My Blog app is not Submiting posts to my Wordpress backend. I keep getting POST https:// net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I created a blog app using cordova; then I hosted the wordpress as the backend on 000webhost.com. My blog-app is retrieving posts from the backend but is not sending posts to the backend as I keep getting an error when I check my console log on chrome inspect.
Here is the code for my blog-app frontend:

````
<html>

<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app-page" data-page="home">
    <div class="app-topbar">
      <div class="app-title">Home page</div>
    </div>
    <div class="app-content">
      <div class="app-section">
        <div class="app-button" data-target="page2">Go to Create Post</div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center pt-2" id="spinner">
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container pt-2" id="mainDiv">

      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Submit a post</h2>
        <form class="was-validated">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="title of post" name="title" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content">Content:</label>
            <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="3" class="form-control" required></textarea>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="app-page" data-page="page2">
    <div class="app-topbar">
      <div class="app-button left" data-back data-autotitle></div>
      <div class="app-title">Create Post</div>
    </div>
    <div class="app-content"></div>

  </div>

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="app.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/index.js"></script>

  <script>
    App.controller('home', function (page) {
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var rootUrl = 'https://temi-tee.000webhostapp.com/';
        /**
        * wordpress url to retrieve all posts from our blog
        */
        const url = `${rootUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`;
        /**
        * wordpress url used to retrieve a token for authentication
        */
        var tokenUrl = `${rootUrl}/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token`;
        /**
        * in this custom scenario, we will be creating posts via admin
        * access however in complex cases you should be able to register
        * new users, the admin username and password is needed to retrieve
        * a token which will be attached
        * as headers to subsequent requests for authentication
        */
        var adminDet = {
          username: 'admin',
          password: '*****'
        };
        /**
        * variable to store token retrived from the api
        */
        var token;
        loadData();
        /**
        * ajax post request to retrieve the token once the app loads
        */
        $.post(tokenUrl, adminDet,
          function (data, status) {
            console.log("token: " + data.token);
            token = data.token;
          });
        /**
        * loadData() function makes a get request to retrieve
        * all posts from the wordpress blog
        */
        function loadData() {
          $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            /**
            * removes the spinner once a response is gotten from the api
            */
            $("#spinner").remove();
            /**
            * ensures that the div tag with id= mainDiv
            * is empty before appending innerHtml to it
            */
            $("#mainDiv").empty();
            /**reiterates through each list in the json oblect
            * while appending it to the div tag with id= mainDiv
            */
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              var div = document.createElement('div');
              div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card pt-1">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">${data[i].title.rendered}</h4>
            <p class="card-text text-wrap">${data[i].content.rendered}</p>
          </div>
        </div>`;
              $("#mainDiv").append(div);
            };
          });
        }
        /**
        * on form submission
        * submits the required parameters to create a new post in the
        * wordpress blog
        */
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
          // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
          event.preventDefault();
          // get the form data
          // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the
          // class or id also)
          var formData = {
            title: $('input[name=title]').val(),
            content: $('textarea[name=content]').val(),
            status: 'publish'
          };
          console.log(formData);
          $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              /**
              * refreshes app-content to display latest posts
              */
              loadData();
            },
            error: function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
        });
      });

    });

    App.controller('page2', function (page) {
      // put stuff here
    });

    try {
      App.restore();
    } catch (err) {
      App.load('home');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>```

This is what the complete error code looks like:
jquery.js:2 POST https://temi-tee.000webhostapp.com//wp-json/wp/v2/posts net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
send        @   jquery.js:2
ajax        @   jquery.js:2
(anonymous) @   index.html:152
dispatch    @   jquery.js:2
v.handle    @   jquery.js:2
````

Comment: I would recommend checking (if possible) if you're able to get any sort of token value from the `${rootUrl}/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` location (or wherever you normally are getting your token value from). If you are not able to get a token at that URL (or wherever the token is normally found), maybe that is related to why the token is undefined. But I don't know if there is some sort of auth that is needed before being able to get a token at that URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your route. If the error response from the endpoint you are using is:

```
{
code: "rest_no_route",
 message: "No route was found matching the URL and request method.",
 data: {
  status: 404
 }
}
```

You might be trying to use GET instead of POST

Make sure you have the correct permalinks option set in Wordpress and the request is a POST request with the correct username etc..